# Copying a file to an Xcode project via a script

Tags: ios, node.js, xcode

I've got a number of targets to build where each of them has a different GoogleAnalytics config file ('GoogleServices-Info.plist'). I seem to be having issue copying the file to an xcode project. Having run the script, the file appears in xcode but it's highlighted in red as if the file actually is missing. The script does not error and all the input files / paths seem to be correct.

```
  const RootFolder = __dirname + '/../..';
  const xcode = require(RootFolder + '/../cordova-node-xcode');
  const IOSFolder = __dirname + '/../../ios';
  const IOSProjectPath = IOSFolder + '/myapp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj';
  const iOSAnalyticsFile = RootFolder + `/res/analytics/${appName}.plist`;
  const iOSDestinationConfigFile = 'GoogleService-Info.plist';
  let iOSFileCopySuccess = false;
  let AndroidFileCopySuccess = false;

  const project = xcode.project(IOSProjectPath);
  project.parseSync();

  // check if the config file has been provided in the /res/analytics folder
  if (fs.existsSync(iOSAnalyticsFile)) {
    try {
      fs.copyFileSync(iOSAnalyticsFile, iOSDestinationConfigFile);
      if (fs.existsSync(iOSDestinationConfigFile)) {
        console.log('file exists'); // all good here
      } else {
        console.log('file is missing');
      }
      project.parse(error => {
        const targetKey = project.findTargetKey(appName); // OK

        const appGroupKey = project.findPBXGroupKey({ name: 'Resources' }); // OK
        project.removeFile(iOSDestinationConfigFile, appGroupKey); // OK
        const f = project.addFile(iOSDestinationConfigFile, appGroupKey, { target: targetKey });
        f.uuid = project.generateUuid();
        project.addToPbxBuildFileSection(f);
        project.addToPbxResourcesBuildPhase(f);

        // Tried the one below as well but the same issue
        // const appGroupKey = project.findPBXGroupKey({ path: 'Resources' });
        // project.removeResourceFile('GoogleService-Info.plist', {}, appGroupKey);
        // project.addResourceFile('GoogleService-Info.plist', {}, appGroupKey);

        fs.writeFileSync(IOSProjectPath, project.writeSync());
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('ERROR', e);
    }
  } else {
    console.log('Missing input files');
  };
```

After running the script I can see the file being referenced a few times in project.pbxproj

Please advise. As we have a large number of targets, each with a different GoogleService-Info, doing it programmatically is the recommended option. Thanks

The file reference appears in xcode project (after opening xcode) but it's in red indicating that the file itself might be missing.